# Porting Litmus-rt to Raspberry Pi. No space left on device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, boot, litmus

I am trying to port `litmus-rt` on to my `Raspberry-pi`. I was done with all the necessary steps like Configuring the Kernel, and Compiling it (compiling it directly in the Raspi) by following the official installation instructions of litmus-rt. But, as I tried to install the kernel with `sudo make install`, I encountered following problem:

> /bin/bash ./arch/arm/boot/install.sh "4.9.30-litmus-g4acc37759358" \
>   arch/arm/boot/Image System.map "/boot" cat: write error: No space left
>   on device arch/arm/boot/Makefile:96: recipe for target 'install'
>   failed make[1]: *** [install] Error 1 arch/arm/Makefile:333: recipe
>   for target 'install' failed make: *** [install] Error 2

And found that my boot partition was being used 100% after trying `df -h`.

Now, to resolve this issue, I tried increasing the size of `boot` partition of the SD Card on my laptop using GParted, but could not increase more than about 42 MB (which was the original size). I tried using the `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get clean` in Raspi, but this also did not help.

I am not sure how to move about this now. Any help will be highly appreciated.

PS: Raspi-3 Model B is running Raspian OS, and has a 64 GB Memory card of which 42 MB is allocated for boot, and out of another 59 GB, I am using only 6 GB.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you found a way? I am confronting the same error

Comment: Hey, yes I solved the issue,
Please follow the discussion at the following link:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=195998